# Python 3, Tkinter: How do I exit the code when I exit out of the window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

```
# Creating the main menu window
root = Tk()

icon2 = PhotoImage(file="Arduino UI Icon 2.png")

root.iconphoto(True, icon2)

# Secondary Window
def LightLED():
    global root
    root.withdraw()    # Hiding, not destroying, the main menu

    ledWin = Tk()    # Creating the secondary window
    ledWin.resizable(False, False)
    ledWin.title("Arduino UI")
    ledWin.geometry('1280x720')

    pinMess = Message(ledWin, text="Enter Pin Number: ", width=200, font=("Arial", 10))
    pinMess.place(x=0, y=10)

    pinEntry = Entry(ledWin, width=3)
    pinEntry.place(x=40, y=35)

    def SetPin():
        global led, pin

        try:
            pin = pinEntry.get()
            led = board.get_pin("d:" + pin + ":p")
        except:
            pass

    pinBut = Button(ledWin, text="Set Pin", width=10, height=1, font=("Arial", 10), 
command=SetPin)
    pinBut.place(x=70, y=32)

    def LEDbOn():
        led.write(1)

    def LEDbOff():
        led.write(0)

    def LEDQuit(): # *Destroying* the secondary window and restoring the main menu window
        global root
        led.write(0)

        ledWin.destroy()    # Completely closing the secondary window
        root.deiconify()    # Restoring the root (MainMenu() window) | where part of the problem is

    ledbOn = Button(ledWin, text="Start", command=LEDbOn, width=8, height=1)
    ledbOn.place(x=170, y=30)

    ledbOff = Button(ledWin, text="Stop", command=LEDbOff)
    ledbOff.place(x=185, y=70)

    ledwinQuit = Button(ledWin, text="Exit", command=LEDQuit)
    ledwinQuit.place(x=187, y=110)

    ledWin.mainloop()
    # Tried "root.destroy()" and "exit()" here and it didn't work (I don't know why)
# It wouldn't work here either because MainMenu() is already called, and LightLED() is called within the function

def MainMenu():    # The main menu window/start up window
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.title("Arduino UI")
    root.geometry('1280x720')

    menubar = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    subMenu = Menu(fileMenu, tearoff=0)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Programs", menu=fileMenu)

    fileMenu.add_command(label="Light LED", command=LightLED)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":    # Starting the program (In the main menu window)
    MainMenu()

exit()    # Exits the code after everything in the MainMenu function is complete
```

So, I want to exit out of the entire program if I X out of the window (Without pressing the Exit button). But, when I do that, because the root is still active and only hidden, the code will not exit out. Then it will keep running as like a background task or something. So, how do I make it exit when I hit the X? I have already tried to put the `exit()` after the `ledWin.mainloop()`, but that doesn't work, and I have no idea why. It also happens when I put the `exit()` after the LightLED function and before the MainMenu function, which makes sense because everything is happening within the MainMenu function. But, is there any place to put it that will close the entire program?

Is there maybe a way to close the root window after I X out of it?

Comment: You are making the problem more difficult than it needs to be by creating two root windows. The second and any subsequent windows should be instance of `Toplevel`.

Comment: once `root.mainloop()` has finished the code has come to its natural end.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% if this is what you meant you are trying to do.

```
# import required module 
from tkinter import *
  
# create object
root = Tk()
  
# create button to implement destroy()
Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack()
  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, sorry if I was unclear in the question. After I X out of the secondary window, I am trying to go back into the main menu window. And since I am only hiding the window, and it is just in a suspended state, when I forcefully close the secondary window by pressing the button on the top right, the main window just stays inactive and suspended. So I am trying to find a way to close the main menu window after I exit out of the secondary window. The main menu window is just hidden by the `root.withdraw()` function.